# How does PHP cURL DNS caching works?

Tags: php, linux, curl, caching, dns

App makes frequent requests to the same domain name of some service.

There are front end requests served by PHP-FPM and there are cron jobs launching multiple PHP command line processes. Almost every time requests to an URL under that domain are performed. Code utilizes Amazon php-sdk which uses cURL for web requests afaik.

How are repeated DNS queries cached (if they are)?

I understand that a single php-fpm worker process is used to process N requests and then is respawned. Is DNS cache shared between multiple php-fpm workers?

Servers runs on CentOS and on Debian. I learned that there is no OS DNS cache by default. Does it make sense to install some OS-wise DNS cache package to cache a single request?

IP address of the service might infrequently change, so hardcoding the ip in `/etc/hosts` is probably not a good idea.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show sample inputs/outputs and your best attempt at code. Sorry, but requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).Good luck.

Comment: No OS DNS cache? Most of systems and DNSes cache domain IP according to TTL (time to live) set by domain owner. You can check site by some DNS tool to see it's cache time: https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3askalski.pro&run=toolpage  (with my page address it shows 60 minutes) DNS cache by default is shared by multiple php-fpm - it's shared across all applications in system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your CentOS and on Debian is configured to handle DNS caching, generally all operating systems are reading the time to refresh the DNS cache from your domain SOA records.

Here is how you can check any domain SOA value:
https://mxtoolbox.com/SOALookup.aspx

**Here is the situation with PHP cURL:**

DNS cache is implemented on cURL on Jan 2002. Read more about it here:

https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2002-01/0076.html

You can turn DNS cache for cURL ON or OFF with

> **CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE**
>   TRUE to use a global DNS cache. This option is not thread-safe and is enabled by default.

Read more on curl options here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php